# How to access underlying struct field value if via interface field type in Golang?

Tags: go, interface

Is there some trick (it is impossible directly) on how to get struct field values via interface?

I have an interface in a file ./animals/mammal.go:

```
type Mammal interface {
     Sound()
}
```

I have implementation in the same file:

```
type Dog struct {
     Name string
     Age int
}

func (d *Dog) Sound {
     fmt.Println("Say my name...", d.Name)
}
```

In other package ../../police/animals.go I have another struct:

```
type Policeman struct {
     Animal Mammal
     Policeman Name
     ID int
}
```

And I wish to be able to implement it like this:

```
func (p *Policeman) Arrest {
     fmt.Println("Hands up, police! Bite him, ", p.Animal.Name)
}
```

And compiler won't let me do that, because p.Animal is an interface type, of course...
However, is there an application design trick/pattern, that could allow me to do that. My point is, that once I wrote Policeman struct, I wish to be sure, that WHEN I CHANGE an animal from Dog to Cat or somebody else, I won't rewrite the "Arrest" method, so that's the point of the question!

Comment: And what would you like to happen with the expression `p.Animal.Name` if the `Mammal` implementation doesn't have a `Name` field? Or perhaps it has no field at all because it's not even a struct? You can access the interface's dynamic type using **type assertion** but then, in your small example, that'd defeat the whole purpose of the interface... just use the concrete type instead. For an example of type assertions see: https://go.dev/tour/methods/15

Comment: Define a Name() method for you interface.  Interfaces don't have fields

Comment: Trying to do inheritance is impossible, just stop trying and redesign.

Answer (score 1):

If, in your context, the following statement is true "All mammals have a name", you can add a method `Name()` to the interface `Mammal` and your example would work like this:

```golang
type Mammal interface {
     Sound()
     Name() string
}

func (p *Policeman) Arrest {
     fmt.Println("Hands up, police! Bite him, ", p.Animal.Name())
}
```

If the statement is not true, then want you want is impossible because it remains unclear what to do with a call to `Name()` for a mammal that does not have a name.

*Note that you then also need to implement the `Name()` method for `Dog`.*

Comment: yes, it could be a solution, however what if I wish to get all fields (be able to get).  The whole idea of this is that I just want to have an ability to abstract in such a way that Policeman won't be bounded to one and only implementation (Dog) of a Mammal, instead, it could change them if needed. But when I do that change, I don't want to rewrite the whole logic been written for Dog specifically... that's the thing... But i think that is ,indeed , impossible

Comment: @Azii I am sure the policeman will have certain 'requirements' as to which animal is suitable and which not. The interface defines those requirements. So in order for the policeman to do an arrest, the animal needs to have ... ? You may come up with whatever you want, but all of them should be in the interface because the policeman and their animal communicate via that interface. BTW if I come up with an `Elephant` that has a `Name()` method (and `Sound()`), your policeman can use it. So it is loosely coupled as in "not bound to one implementation" as you stated.